# Trigger a Google Cloud Function on file upload to Azure Blob Storage using Event Grid

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, azure-eventgrid

I would like to trigger a Cloud Function on Google Cloud every time a file is uploaded to or updated in an Azure Blob Storage container. The function on GCP will then load and perform some operations on this new file in the Blob container. To test that the communication from Azure Blob Storage to Google Cloud Functions is working correctly, I have created a very simple function with the following body:

```
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def hello_get(request):

    return "Hello World!"
```

On the Azure side, we have created a web hook subscribing to changes in the Blob Storage container where the endpoint provided is the Cloud Function Trigger URL. When deploying the event subscription on the Azure side, however, we receive the error:

"Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for **function trigger URL**. Http POST request retuned 2XX response with response body Hello World!. When a validation request is accepted without validation code in the response body, Http GET is expected on the validation url included in the validation event(within 10 minutes). For troublehooting, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity id:xxxxx, timestamp: 9/5/2023 2:55:41 PM (UTC)."}"

I would like to understand the reason for this error. Is the problem on the side of Azure or the side of GCP? The ingress settings of the Cloud Function is to allow all traffic, and the service account running the Cloud Function has all the required IAM permissions to invoke the function.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, it's not a problem on Cloud Functions. It's on Azure side. I don't know it. It requires a validation of the message, but what is it? Maybe that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-event-grid-events

Comment: From the error message, it would seem that your webhook is not following Event Grid's authentication requirements.   I'd suggest reading over the link embedded in the error message.   I've retagged this to better surface it to those with more expertise for Event Grid.